# How to analyze (compare groups) time series survey data

Tags: regression, time-series, statistical-significance, survey, trend

I'm seeking help in determining the best form of analysis for some time series survey data I've collected. To keep it simple, here's a hypothetical example of the data and desired analysis:

- Weekly survey (40 weeks, 100 respondents per week) about how much respondents like/dislike apples.
- Different respondents each week.
- Overall trend has various curves, with attitudes becoming more positive, then more negative, then more positive again.

What I'd like to test:

- Are there significant trends in the data (i.e., attitudes changing over time)?
- Are there differences between males/females, in terms of one liking apples more than the other?
- Are there differences between the trends for males/females? For example, maybe in Week 1 males exhibited a slightly more positive view towards apples than females, but over time that gap grew as males' attitudes became more much positive and females attitudes' became only a bit more positive.

Many thanks for any and all assistance!